# logstash script_lang not supported [groovy]

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I am using logstash to update my index in elasticsearch from a csv file.
Below is my configuration file

```
input {
 //input from a csv file
}

filter {

}

output {
elasticsearch{
                action => "update"
                document_id => "%{PRODUCT_ID}"
                doc_as_upsert => "true"
                hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
                index => "product"
                script_lang => "groovy"
                script => //some groovy script
 }
}
```

I am getting following error:

```
"status"=>400, 
"error"=>{
"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception",
 "reason"=>"failed to execute script", 
"caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception",
 "reason"=>"script_lang not supported [groovy]"}}
```

I am using elasticsearch v7.5 and logstash v7.3

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for the `groovy` scripting language has been [removed in ES 6.0](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/21607).

You now have the choice between the [Lucene expression language](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-expression.html) and the [Painless scripting language](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-painless.html). You should probably rewrite your Groovy logic using Painless.